# How to open a page inside overlay on clicking RichtextLink | DD4T MVC4 site | Tridion 2013 SP1

Tags: dd4t

In CMS I have attached the component inside richtext as a link. When i publish the page the HTML of the link inside the richtext is rendered as

```
> <a title="Signup" target="overlay"
> href="http://MysiteURL/Myform.aspx"><strong>Sing up today!</strong>&nbsp;</a>
```

I want to open the Myform.aspx page as overlay on clicking the link.

At DD4T solution i am using below code to render rich text.

```
@if (Model.Component.Fields.ContainsKey("description")) {        <p>@Model.Component.Fields["description"].Value.ResolveRichText()</p>  
}
```

If anyone can help me to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this question is not really tridion-related, but can simply be solved using a javascript library.

Some plugins are at your disposal (jquery based)

http://jquerytools.github.io/demos/overlay/external.html

http://tutorialzine.com/2012/07/framewarp-jquery-plugin/